# My mathematics PhD application at Michigan State University

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics

I got an email from the mathematics graduate department of Michigan State University, which mentioned that I was being nominated for a fellowship, and hence they needed certain documents. I confirmed if that meant that I have been provisionally admitted, and their answer was positive. It has been three weeks since they sent me that email, and I still haven't received an official confirmation or an offer letter. When can I expect to get that, and why is it taking so long?

Comment: If they are considering you for a fellowship, you are essentially certainly admitted.  However, they will presumably need to determine whether they are actually going to offer you the fellowship before sending you the formal acceptance, because until the fellowship is decided, they cannot tell you what financial package they are offering.

Comment: Perhaps there have been holidays.  Perhaps the pandemic is leading to staffing shortages.   Perhaps email is an unreliable medium.

Comment: Or maybe they've sent a snail mail for whatever formal reasons and the OP is due for a few more months of waiting.